# Shell script - Can't do things after compress folder

Tags: bash, shell, compression, ubuntu-14.04

When i try to do something when i have runned the `zip` command it wont work.

This is my script now:

```
#!/bin/bash 
TIME=BACKUPMC-`date +%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M`.zip
zip -r $TIME /home/daixhosting/d1
```

That works fine. But when i try do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
TIME=BACKUPMC-`date +%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M`.zip
zip -r $TIME /home/daixhosting/d1
echo "Done"
```

It wont work.. the output is this:

```
zip warning: name not matched: /home/daixhosting/d1

). -i /home/daixhosting/d1(try: zip -r BACKUPMC-03-08-2015-14:26.zip
done
```

Even if i make the destination folder a varibale it gives me the same error.

What can the couse be?

Thank you

Comment: Your script probably has DOS line endings (which explains the jumbled-looking error message), and the last line of the script is terminated only by the end of the file (which explains why the first script works but the second script does not).

Comment: See the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) step 1 for more information about DOS line endings, how to detect them and how to remove them.

Comment: @thatotherguy i do not really understand how to remove ^M...

Comment: @CasperRasmussen You mean you don't understand the suggestion of "If you find them, delete them using `dos2unix` (a.k.a. `fromdos`) or `tr -d '\r'`"?

Comment: If Windows was involved in the creation or copying to ubuntu, then you need to use `dos2unix myscript` once you have transferred the file. Good luck.

Comment: Awesome @shellter! It worked, thank you!

Comment: promise me you'll reread #1 on http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info :-) Welcome to S.O. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy something into your script from somewhere? Either search for

```
\r\n
```

in your script or type exactly the same into a new file created on the target OS.

Answer (score 0):

Tried at my end, and I got the warning

```
zip warning: name not matched:
```

only when the directory path I was trying to ZIP was wrong (incorrect), otherwise script worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: It's working when i don't have anything after the zip command. But when I add the echo thing, or something else it gives me that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
TIME="$BACKUPMC""$(date +'%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M')"".zip"
zip --recurse-paths --quiet "$TIME" "/home/daixhosting/d1"
echo "DONE"
```

Comment: @CasperRasmussen BACKUPMP isn't a variable? If not, then change first line of code to `TIME="BACKUPMC""$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')"".zip"`, and try again.